# Why does an old version of a file not exist after switching to an old branch?

Tags: git

While on my way to learn some git basics I was given a task (on githowto.com website) to create a new branch (called "style") and change and commit my existing file using style branch.

The file was on master branch before, because I didn't know how to create or change branches yet. So I changed my file, committed it while in style branch and then switched to master branch. In the tutorial it was said that if I type in `git cat *filename*` I'm gonna see the version of my file last committed in master branch (before changings that were done in style branch), but surprisingly git told me that this file doesn't exist.

```
$ cat lib/hello.html
cat: lib/hello.html: No such file or directory
```

I did everything exactly in a way it was said in the instructions on the site mentioned previously. I have absolutely no idea of what went wrong.

Edit: i solved the problem. I just didn't notice my commits at some point stopped to be marked with "master" in history. that means my HEAD went in a different way from master branch. the version of file that was committed and marked with master has opened(cated) without any issues. So now its all clear.

Comment: If you committed a file to an "old" branch, that file should be visible in that branch.  Period.  If you later deleted the file from that branch, it won't be visible in the current ("HEAD") revision.  The same with "master"  (or equivalently Git "main"): If you committed the file to master, it should be visible to master.

Comment: You typed `cat lib/hello.html`, not `git cat lib/hello.html`.

Comment: i think i got it: my master branch detached at a certain moment: so in hist i saw how HEAD and master were in different commits(that means at some point HEAD parted ways from master, and i even now at what point). When i tried to cat a commit marked with master it actually cated, so i see the problem now. Thanks for your comment. It pointed me a direction to work on. Appreciated

Comment: `git cat` is going to give you an error message unless you have some kind of alias set up.

Answer (score 0):

Whatever you are learning from may not be the best choice, because it is clear that it has not explained to you what Git *is*. But that's okay because we're here to explain it to you!

So let's look at it like this:

- First of all there is no such thing as a file being "on a branch."
- *Nothing* is really "on a branch" except for *you.*
- And this matters only when you *make a commit*.
- Commits are the *only thing Git contains*.
- And what is a commit? It is a snapshot of *all your files* — but only to the extent that Git *knows* about them. Git does not know about a file until you add-and-commit it.

So let's try to reconstruct what you did. Of course I don't really know what you did, so I have to guess. This is my guess:

1. Let's say *you* were on `master` branch and you create and edit your file *filename*.
2. Then you realize you are supposed to be on the `style` branch. So you create your `style` branch and switch to it, so that *you* are on the `style` branch.
3. Now you edit your file *filename* some more, and you add-and-commit *filename*.
4. Finally, you switch back so that *you* are on the `master` branch.

Now, how many times did I say "commit" in that little story? I said it *once*. And where were you when you made that one commit? You were on `style`. You were not on `master`! You *never* did an add-and-commit of *filename* when you were on `master`. While you were on `master`, you never told Git about *filename*. So `master` doesn't know about *filename* at all.

So now when you switch from `style` to `master`, you don't see *filename*. That's because no version of *filename* has been ever committed while you were on `master`. As far as `master` is concerned, *filename* doesn't exist.

Comment: you might also want to explain about "HEAD" (every branch has a "HEAD", including "master") and about "git cat *filename*" (by default, there's no such thing).